# Nested JSON with Incrementing Key Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to read a nested JSON message where they key values are incrementing integer values but it does not seem to work.

```
$.each(data.post, function(entryIndex, entry) {
    $.each(this.entryIndex, function() {
        alert(this.username);
    });
});
```

Sorry, I tried to paste the JSON code here, but I kept on getting a formatting error. Instead, I have uploaded the JSON [here](http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/example.json).

Comment: Can we see the JSON you are working with? Are you sure the JSON string has been parsed into an object?

Comment: Could you provide the json object structure? Maybe some example data that it would contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went a level too deep:

```
    $.each(data.posts, function() {

            alert(this.username);

    });​
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/8sb8j/2/

This will get you the usernames of the replies:

```
    $.each(data.posts, function() {

        $.each(this.replies, function(){
            alert(this.username);
        });

    });​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.posts, function(entryIndex, entry) {
    alert(this.username);
});
```